# Telebot sub menu

Tags: python, menu, telegram-bot, submenu

I am creating a bot in telegram and I have a menu. The thing is that every time someone chooses an option a new message is sent instead of modifying the menu. I understand that this is because of the send_message function, but I don't know how to do it.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['menu'])
def menu(message):
   keyboard = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
   keyboard.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton('Reglas', callback_data='Reglas'))
   keyboard.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton('Consultas', callback_data='Consultas'))
   keyboard.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton('Historia', callback_data='Historia'))
   keyboard.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton('Tiradas', callback_data='Tiradas'))
   keyboard.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton('Admin', callback_data='adm'))
   bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Has llamado al menu?',reply_markup=keyboard)
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda c:True)
def submenus(c):
        if c.data == 'Tiradas':
    keyboard = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    keyboard.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton('Tirada suelta', callback_data='ts'))
    keyboard.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton('Tirada de personajes',callback_data='tp'))
    bot.send_message(c.message.chat.id, 'Deseas tiradas sueltas o para crear personajes?', reply_markup=keyboard)
```

I started programming a few weeks ago, I beg your patience. Thank you very much for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

So... This is happening because of your lack of study in the telegram api. If you want to edit the message instead of sending a new one, you simply won't use send_message!

You will use edit_message_text, In this case your code would look like this:

```
bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=c.message.chat.id, message_id=c.message.message_id, text='Deseas tiradas sueltas o para crear personajes?', reply_markup=keyboard)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the truth is that I don't have much idea of programming very well. Thanks for your time